# Modify Deserializer for a Creator Property to handle unwrapped field of a different type

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I am trying to write custom deserialization handling using Jackson (2.14.0) to address common boilerplate repeated in our DTO/POJO classes used in our integrations.

We currently use DTOs to handle all integration schema complexity (field name differences, type differences, wrapping/unwrapping fields) - and I specifically want to remove some of these DTOs with replacement annotations / custom deserializers where common patterns are repeated but also formulaic.

My current problem is one use case where there are multiple schema complications existing simultaneously:

- The serialized format is UNWRAPPED relative to the POJO
- The serialized format's unwrapped fields are named differently (it's a deterministic name change, but not a simple prefix/suffix, despite my examples)
- The serializes format's unwrapped fields are TYPED differently

```java
/* 
  POJOs
*/
class Foo {
    TimeRange timeRange;
}

class TimeRange {
    long start;
    long end;
}

/*
  DTOs - an exact mirror of what JSON is transmitted
*/
class FooDTO {
    String startDateTime;
    String endDateTime;
}
```

My tentative solution for this is to register custom deserialization `SimpleModule`s - by using a new annotation on the POJO fields - that registers and changes fields using `BeanDeserializerModifier`s. Fields can then opt into the special logic by using a custom annotation. Like:

```java
class Foo {
    @JsonTimeRange(format = "ISO_DATE_TIME")
    TimeRange timeRange;
}

class TimeRange {
    long start;
    long end;

    @JsonCreator TimeRange(final long start, final long end) { ... }
}
```

The one I have working so far for this `TimeRange` use case attempts to use existing Jackson `@JsonUnwrapped` logic present in `BeanDeserializer/Base` and I feel is SO CLOSE to working perfectly.

My problem as I can see it is I do not know how to effectively propagate state down in the deserialization hierarchy.

Jackson handles `@JsonUnwrapped` by taking the original `BeanDeserializer` associated with the class and building virtual bean properties matching the transformed names. When deserializing it scans a copied token buffer looking for those values and injects those properties into the base deserializer as if they had always been there. The base deserializer then operates normally, barely cognizant of the difference.

In my case, I'm hoping to leverage the existing `@JsonCreator` for `TimeRange`. The trouble is that it's _`creatorProperties` is built with a `LongDeserializer` for it's own fields when built by Jackson (which is technically correct) - and I cannot find how how in the world to intercept these and replace them. I can build the exact "String To Long Deserializer" required when processing `@JsonTimeRange` but that state is nowhere to be found when processing the `BeanDeserializer` for `TimeRange`.

I also can't seem to find a place to re-intercept `Foo.timeRange` - neither the property NOR the deserializer - in a way that matters.

- I can retrieve the canonical deserializer for `TimeRange` from `DeserializationContext` when building my custom property - but I can't reach down into `deserializer -> bean properties -> creator -> creator properties -> deserializer` and swap anything out. it's all hidden and immutable by this point
- `ContextualDeserializer#createContextual` as executed by `BeanDeserializer` is the most often cited place in other posts I have read, but it's insufficient for my intention here for what seems to be the same reason - cannot access and change the fields I need to.

I accept that my desire to use as much vanilla Jackson as possible - including relying on the standard `JsonCreator` for `TimeRange`, and how it processes "Unwrapped" fields (`NameTransformer`, `UnwrappedPropertyHandler`, and their retrievals within `BeanDeserializer#resolve`) - may be too much to expect.

But on the other hand it SEEMS to fit so well and I'm hoping there's a connection between these deserialization levels I can utilize to dynamically tweak the CreatorProperties for TimeRange just enough to let it go. The error I get right now is just type type difference.

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `long` from String "2019-01-01T08:00:00.000Z": not a valid `long` value
 at [Source: (String)"{"startDateTime":"2019-01-01T08:00:00.000Z","endDateTime":"2019-01-01T18:00:00.000Z"}"; line: 1, column: 141] (through reference chain: com.my.project.TimeRange["startDateTime"])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `long` from String "2019-01-01T08:00:00.000Z": not a valid `long` value
 at [Source: (String)"{"startDateTime":"2019-01-01T08:00:00.000Z","endDateTime":"2019-01-01T18:00:00.000Z"}"; line: 1, column: 141] (through reference chain: com.my.project.TimeRange["startDateTime"])
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1996)
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:1224)
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseLongPrimitive(StdDeserializer.java:916)
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseLongPrimitive(StdDeserializer.java:904)
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$LongDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:573)
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers$LongDeserializer.deserialize(NumberDeserializers.java:550)
    at app//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:542)
```

Also open to alternatives, but this seems the most Jackson-like solution to me for this problem since they already have some support for Unwrapped fields!